# Problem aligning blocks horizontally in Opera

Tags: html, css, opera, horizontal-scrolling

I have [this wide page](http://d43.me/storage/examples/opera-wide-page-problem/) with an information block and lot of images to the right of it. It is supposed to be used with horizontal scrollbar.

The page works as expected in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, even in IE7+ — but it does not do so in the latest Opera. In Opera, the block with images goes beneath the information block if they do not fit into the window in one line.

I've tried a lot of things. I even re-wrote it all using tables — that helped for Opera, but this way I lost dynamic image height functionality in Chrome which is essential for me. At the same time, I think I'm missing something simple here.

Any advice is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#panorama {
  margin-left:400px;
}
```

this fix it in my version of Opera, but don't know then if it will be compatible with the other browsers also.